# Ordering-Sorting on runtime in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sorting, mysqli

My DB schema is like `Course_Table` `{course_name,marks,std_ID}`
I am getting only 1 subject marks for a particluar student,Therefore my flow of Logic and presnetation is

```
$std_id=Select std_id From student_Table


 foreach(Iterate all students)
 select marks from course_table where std_ID=student_ID
 {
Print Student marks  //here i need sorted List,,,
 }
My problem is not actually  the Code,I am looking for logic
```

I want to Print the student marks in ascending Order.

- What I thought is to use `Order By` clause,but it is of no use as I am getting only 1 record per student .
- may Be I need to create a sepreate class,Fed all the data inside this class and then Sort it.. (a very hectic approach would be my last option)
- I am looking for an alternative approach or logic that could solve my query.

Comment: Nice way to explain the query, may be the best approach would to create a seperate class.You can't sort the list until you get all the values of marks.

Comment: depending on your db design, there may be a way to use a single query to select them at once and sort using `ORDER BY`.